# changing value of python dictionary to create a pyload

Tags: python, dictionary, key-value

how do i modify a prop default value, i want to keep all default values initially and base on the requirement i want to modify a specific prop default value. for example i want to modify prop3 default value to data1 but then next time i run i want to keep all prop default and change prop8 default value.

```
def property_value(prop_name, value)
  data = {
    "id": 104,
    "content": "prop1=default_value\n"
               "prop2=default_value\n"
               "prop3=default_value\n"
               "prop4=default_value\n"
               "prop5=default_value\n"
               "prop6=default_value\n"
               "prop7=default_value\n"
               "prop8=default_value"
    }
  res = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=data)
```

Comment: maybe create normal dictionary with values, and later convert it to string

Comment: you may have to `copy()` dictionary before changes. It may need to use module `copy`

Comment: if you will keep `data` inside function then when you will run function then it will always create the same dictionary with default values

Comment: @furas can u show me how to copy and then modify?

Comment: I would rather keep it as dictionary `content = {"prop1" "default_value", "prop2" "default_value", ..}` and change it as `content[prop_name] = value` and later convert it to string which I would add to `data`. And if you will keep `data` inside function then it will create new data (with default values) everytime when you run function - because it is local variable which is create again and again when you run function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`data` is local variable - so when you run again function then it creates it again with default values.

Problem is only to replace value in `content`. I would keep it as dictionary `content = {"prop1" "default_value", "prop2" "default_value", ..}` and replace value `content[prop_name] = value` and later convert it to one string and put in this string in `data`

```
def property_value(prop_name, value):
    content = {
        "prop1": "default_value",
        "prop2": "default_value",
        "prop3": "default_value",
        "prop4": "default_value",
        "prop5": "default_value",
        "prop6": "default_value",
        "prop7": "default_value",
        "prop8": "default_value",
    }
    
    content[prop_name] = value
    
    text = [f'{key}={val}' for key, val in content.items()]
    text = "\n".join(text)
    
    data = {
        "id": 104,
        "content": text,
    }
    
    print(data)
    
    #res = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=data)

# --- main ---

property_value('prop1', 'ABC')
property_value('prop4', 'XYZ')
```